# iPhone Packager AS3 failing to convert switch case statement?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, case, switch-statement

So, I've been creating an application using the Adobe AIR Packager for iPhone (command line style).
The app consists of a lot of screens that provide various information, and the navigation is handled all in the document class via an event-triggered function that uses a large switch-case statement to determine what screen to go to.

When we compiled it through the iPhone Packager and tried to test it on one of our phones, it would load up to a blank screen.

After some error testing it was revealed that the switch-case itself is causing a problem (changing it to an if-else that had the same functionality worked just fine). Does anyone know whether this is a known issue, or if something can be done to fix that other than converting it to an if-else.

If all else fails, it will be converted to the if-else style statement, but I was just wondering if this was a known issue and if a fix is available...

**EDIT:** We found that 3 of our cases the switch were causing the issue. None of these cases' results have anything abnormal in them; even commenting out the entire class file that was created by the case caused it to fail out (commenting the case out, however, works).

It doesn't seem like there is anything we can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say anything without code, but it sounds like a bug in the packager. You should report it to Adobe.